# Issue with mobile/particles/alpha-blended on Unity iOS build

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, shader

I've ran into a problem while developing a game in Unity and deploying to iOS.

I have a GameObject which is meant to be a transparent goal net(think Football/soccer). I've created a material with a net texture and made it use the Particles/alpha-blended because I've read online that it works best for transparent two-sided objects.

The texture applied to the material is tiled to form a larger net, and it works well, both in the editor and on an Android device. When deploying to iOS however, the tiling doesn't happen. Instead, the main texture is stuck to the top right corner and the rest of the surface gets the edges of the main image stretched all over it.

Does anybody know the reason behind it? Keep in mind, it's an iOS only issue, as it works well in both the Unity Editor and on Android.

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer on the Unity forums, IOS experiences artifacts with UVs too far beyond the range of 0-1, I imagine for your football net texture you're way beyond that.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/14046/tiling-textures-in-unity-for-iphone.html

I'd suggest you have a different texture for your IOS build that doesn't need to be tiled so much.

Answer (score 0):

As Edward Andrew pointed out this is caused by a small maximum UV range on IOS Metal, when tiling textures (Texture set to repeat). A quick workaround I found for this is simply repeating the UV with a mod function on the shader frag function (doing this on the vert function produces artifacts related to UV interpolation):

```
fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
{
    fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv % 1.0);
}
```